# How to set path of multiple custom apps in django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-settings, django-apps

Can anyone please help me with this.
MyProject is the name of my project in django with two different apps **HappyHomes** and **HappyHomesAdmin**.

I want to switch from **HappyHomes** to **HappyHomesAdmin**.

How to set path in urls file? How many files in total I will need? And also how to set path of switching to different app in `views.py` file in django.

I am here `C:/Users/MaitRi/Desktop/PROJECT/MyProject/HappyHomes/templates/reg.html`
and want to move at `C:/Users/MaitRi/Desktop/PROJECT/MyProject/HappyHomesAdmin/templates/home.html`

Comment: What do you mean by "move"? Do you want URLs from templates of one app pointing to another, redirects between pages, or you want to rename your app? Do you want to implement redirection from registration page to admin home page after successfull registration?

Comment: yes. I mean i want to switch from registration page to admin app that is HappyHomesAdmin and reg page is in HappyHomes.

Answer (score 0):

In your folder that has same name of your project, i think is MyProject, inside the urls.py you need to set a path, as below

In urls.py of your project:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    path('HappyHomes/', include('HappyHomes.urls')),
    path('HappyHomesAdmin/', include('HappyHomesAdmin.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

You have to define your app name in the urls.py of HappyHomes, for example:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "HappyHomes" #example

urlpatterns = [...]
```

You have to define your app name in the urls.py of HappyHomesAdmin, for example:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "HappyHomesAdmin" #example

urlpatterns = [...
               path(
                    'home/', 
                     views.name_views, 
                     name='home'),...]
```

in a views.py of a HappyHomes, you can just:

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponseRedirect, reverse
    def example(request):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('HappyHomesAdmin:home')) #home is the name of the url
```